# Multivariate Regression: Gradient Descent Definition Error

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

```
def gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, i):
J = []  #cost function in each iterations
k = 0
while k < i:        
    y1 = hypothesis(theta, X)
    y1 = np.sum(y1, axis=1)
    for c in range(0, len(X.columns)):
        theta[c] = theta[c] - alpha*(sum((y1-y)*X.iloc[:,c])/len(X))
    j = computeCost(X, y, theta)
    J.append(j)
    k += 1
return J, j, theta
J, j, theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, 0.05, 10000)
```

If i run this code, an error would appear as follows:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-d17a8fb83984> in <module>()
----> 1 J, j, theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, 0.05, 10000)

<ipython-input-62-bfec0d0edcfa> in gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, i)
      6         y1 = np.sum(y1, axis=1)
      7         for c in range(0, len(X.columns)):
----> 8             theta[c] = theta[c] - alpha*(sum((y1-y)*X.iloc[:,c])/len(X))
      9         j = computeCost(X, y, theta)
     10         J.append(j)

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable
```

I hope there is any solution for this immediately. Thankyou.

Comment: please fix the indentation in your code

Comment: please provide a minimum reproducible example (what values are you using for X, y, theta)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: X = df.drop(columns="Math")
y = df.iloc[:, 4]

The dataset is consists of five columns.
The first is the column of ones for the bias term.
The second until the last are int64 consisting numerical value from 1-100. The second field represents the Physics scores, the third represents the Science scores, the fourth represents the Statistics scores, while the last one represents the Math scores. I am trying to use the 1st until the 4th column to predict the 5th column (Math).